# Not get duplicates in math random

Tags: c#, math, blazor

I want my index to be a random number that is equal to my questions. I have a list of 33 questions which is indexed from 0-32. I have this idea that I will get random questions everytime with help of my index. This works but I still get duplicates. How do I prevent this?

```
 @if (questionIndex23 < 10)
        {
            <div class="app-title">
                @Questions[kuken].Category
            </div>
```

Here I get a random category from my list "question" with help of my index.

```
public void Hannes()
    {
        Random slump = new Random();
        kuken = slump.Next(1, 32);
    }
```

This is the method I've written to get random numbers for my index.

Comment: create a list of integers and write a function to fill it the function would work like generate a random number and store it in the list but ignore the generated number if it exist in the list and retry

Comment: Just shuffle a set of numbers representing the indexes of the questions and then consume that shuffled list from start to end.

Comment: Random numbers *can* be duplicated in a truly random sequence, just as a dice can return 6 more than once if you throw it 6 times. What you're looking for is shuffling.

Comment: Adding to @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggestion. `Enumerable.Range(0, 32).OrderBy(_ => Random.Shared.Next()).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffle your questions

```
Random slump = new Random();
Questions = Questions.OrderBy(_ => slump.Next()).ToList();
```

before displaying them

```
@foreach(var question in Questions)
{
    < div class="app-title">
        @question.Category
    </div>
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't work. It's just stuck on question number one.

Comment: what doesn't work? The `OrderBy()` or the `foreach`

Comment: It displays the whole list. I want to get one question at the time.

Comment: ok then you have to remember the number of asked questions `int currentQuestion = 0;` and increment it each time a qestion is asked `currentQuestion++;` and `Questions[currentQuestion ]` - wasn't clear how your question thing works

Comment: btw, you can do `Random.Shared.Next()` in .net7 and make it one-liner.

Comment: @Alamakanambra since .net6 actually.